# How to raise a table cell above keyboard level with textfield inside that cell is focused?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using the following to raise a textfield inside a table cell above keyboard level. But this only works if I tap the textfield. If I focus the text field programmatically ,i.e., `[textField becomeFirestResponder]`, it doesn't work. *Edit*: also `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` is being called but the code inside isn't performing as expected.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     CGPoint pointInTable = [textField.superview convertPoint:textField.frame.origin toView:_tableView];
     CGPoint contentOffset = _tableView.contentOffset;
     contentOffset.y = (pointInTable.y - textField.inputAccessoryView.frame.size.height);
     [_tableView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: If you manage the table view with a `UITableViewController` (or a subclass of that), it should take care of the problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the `[self textFieldShouldBeginEditing:textField]` after setting `[textField becomeFirstResponder]`

Comment: `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` is getting called, but is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

call `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` and implement your keyboard avoiding code in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` as it is called after editing has begun. On the other hand `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` is called before beginning editing. You can properly obtain the keyboard height after editing has begun.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party class **TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView** 
Which will automatically adjust and scroll TableView when keyboard get opens.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding